# Gmail IMAP OAuth2 returns error code 400

Tags: gmail, oauth-2.0, imap, gmail-imap

When trying to connect to the Google IMAP service using the XOAUTH2 mechanism (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol), I sometimes receive the following error response:

```
{"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what exactly that status 400 was ...

Answer (score 1):

Error message seems to happen when you use an expired access token.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700114/error-code-400-on-generating-oauth-2-sasl-string). It is due to the Gmail scope("https://mail.google.com/") was missing, from the token generation process.