# Error code 400 on generating OAuth 2 SASL string

Tags: oauth-2.0, imap, gmail-imap, sasl

I have generated the following SASL string FOR OAuth 2:

> user=designadmin@mydesign.mygbiz.com^Aauth=Bearer 
>   ya29.AHES6ZTtYOu0NR0vAYbrvKZNcHJPuZEpr4Hk3W3dXcXFQ88^A^A

Then i encoded it and sent the encoded string like this:

> MSB AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 *encoded string*

But i get error response as:

> {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}

What does this error mean and how can i correct it?

Comment: Are you putting in caret-a, or control a (code point 1)

Comment: Yes , i have tried with "^A" and "\001" both.

Comment: Use \001. Also print out the IMAP error, in the bad or no response, which has more information than just the 400.

Comment: I get the same error. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. In my case, the Gmail scope("https://mail.google.com/") was missing, from the token generation process. It works fine now.

EDIT:

(Including comment from @ohmyfromage:)

When you call `generateAuthUrl`, you need to pass an object with an array scope of strings as the scopes, and one of those strings is "https://mail.google.com/"

Comment: can you explain in more detail?

Comment: When you call `generateAuthUrl`, you need to pass an object with an array `scope` of strings as the scopes, and one of those strings is `"https://mail.google.com/"`.

Answer (score 1):

*+1 to akshay for self answering.*

This can also happen if you are using an expired token. If that is the case, just re authenticate your user and use the new token.